# How can I connect 2 laptops using bluetooth of ubuntu 11.10 & transfer files?

Tags: bluetooth

I have used "hcitool scan" command but it can'nt find any address of other laptops but can detect phones . How can i connect 2 laptops ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the other laptop is visible. Use the gnome or unity UI or if you don't have a desktop refer to this link- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1530253.

You can also make an adhoc network and then share the files.